# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enter')

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, node-telegram-bot-api, telegraf.js

please tell me why the scenes in telegraf.js stopped working for me. Yesterday everything worked fine, but today they seem to have been removed from the framework Telegraf.js

```
const nameScene = new Scenes.BaseScene('name');
nameScene.enter((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('Please enter your name:');
});



nameScene.on('text', (ctx) => {
    if (!ctx.message.text) {
        ctx.reply('The name is required!');
        return;
    }

    ctx.session.name = ctx.message.text;
    ctx.scene.enter('surname');

});
// Scene 'surname'
const surnameScene = new Scenes.BaseScene('surname');
surnameScene.enter((ctx) => ctx.reply('Enter your last name:'));
surnameScene.on('text', (ctx) => {
    ctx.session.surname = ctx.message.text;
    ctx.scene.enter('city');
});

const cityScene = new Scenes.BaseScene('city');

const Stage = new Scenes.Stage([
    nameScene,
    surnameScene,
    cityScene,
]);
bot.use(Stage.middleware());
return Stage;


bot.action('fill_form', async (ctx) => {
    await ctx.answerCbQuery();
    await ctx.scene.enter('name');
});
```

I will be very grateful if you help